# image name repeating in multiple image selection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am trying to show the image name also in multiple image upload.in case of single selection its working but in case of multiple selection image name Repeats. please check my fiddle. am also trying to show the image path

Comment: Just for a good practice please include your link to the fiddle in the actual question, not in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change:

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kojL0pk/

```
var f = $('.trnsupload').prop("files")[0]['name'];
```

To

```
var f = $('.trnsupload').prop("files")[i]['name'];
```

// Full Code:

```
window.Transfer = function (input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     $(input.files).each(function (i) { // add index over here 
       var f = $('.trnsupload').prop("files")[i]['name']; // access file using i-th index
       var reader = new FileReader(); 
       reader.readAsDataURL(this);
       reader.onload = function (e) {
         $("#Viewer").append("<div class='imageContainer'><img onclick='changeIt(this)'  class='thumb img-thumbnail' src='" + e.target.result + "'>     <span class='MultiFile-title'>" + f + "</span>        <span class='loader'><img src='../../Images/ajax-loader.gif' /></span> <span class='closeCover glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></div>");
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: if you want to get realpath of an image then its not possible due to security reasons.

Comment: i mean uploaded image path

Comment: iam trying to alert the image path while uploading time. but it shows the base 64 path fully. how to convert that to real path?